# How to read app.properties file from Java Spark application

Tags: java, apache-spark, configuration, amazon-emr

I implemented Java Spark application, which I'm running on EMR cluster with spark-submit command.
I want to pass app.properties which I use in my application.
app.properties looks as follows:

```
local_fetcher = false
local_storage = false
local_db = true
.
.
.
```

I want to be able to get this data in my application.
My questions are:

1. Where app.properties should be located?
2. How can I read it content in my Spark application?
3. Should I be able to read it from driver & executers?

I tried to use `--properties-file` flag but I understood it will override the default Spark configuration which is not what I want.
I saw that I might use `--file` flag, but didn't understand where should the file be located and how I can read it inside my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### First option: --files

> --files FILES Comma-separated list of files to be placed in the working directory of each executor. File paths of these files in executors can be accessed via SparkFiles.get(fileName).

```
spark-submit --files /path/to/app.properties /path/to/your/fat/jar.jar
```

You can get the exact location of the uploaded file using the [SparkFiles](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkFiles.html).

#### Second option: getResourceAsStream

Put your app.properties inside your job's JAR file, and load it like this:

```scala
val appPropertiesStream = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(
  classOf[yourObject].getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("/app.properties")

val appPropertiesString = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(appPropertiesStream ).mkString
```

(note the forward slash before the "app.properties", as far as I remember it's important)

Comment: Oleg thank you for your comment. In the first options the driver won't have access to this file, if I understand correctly.. What about the second option?